# How to access kubernetes cluster that sits in a remote server, from my local python code?

Tags: python, kubernetes, ssh

What I'm trying to do is mimic what I do in the terminal:
In the terminal I can SSH into a remote server, and then use the "kubectl" api to look at pods, jobs etc.

I'm trying to do the same from my local Python code, with the [kubernetes package](https://pypi.org/project/kubernetes/)

I tried using SSHTunnelForwarder

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
```

with every configuration possible but could not get it to work. Any advice would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: "In the terminal I can SSH into a remote server" What does your ssh command look like? Presumably you are configuring some port forwarding options. "with every configuration possible" Show us your code that you believe corresponds to the ssh command line you are using.

Comment: If you use the `ssh -L` option to forward the Kubernetes API server port back to your local system, and then use `kubectl` locally; then with this setup you can use a normal Kubernetes SDK with the same `~/.kube/config` file.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks, this seems to work (Done the same in my Python code), although my remote server denies the connection, probably a setting that needs to be changed in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: @larsks Thanks you're right, my code really did not correspond to the ssh command.